# Best way to check object/variable type in Java

Tags: java, android

I have many types of activity's, but if at a certain point `activity` is a `TaskComplianceActivity` then I want to handle it in a special way.

I could do:

```
if (activity.getClass().getName() == "au.net.example.myapp.TaskComplianceActivity")
```

But that is very ugly.

I have tried this, but it didn't work:

```
if (activity instanceof TaskComplianceActivity)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can cleanly do this?

Comment: Second way is right what problem u are getting?

Comment: The first way wouldn´t work, since you don´t compare strings that way. The second way with `instanecof` would also include a `null` check

Comment: If I step through the code I see: Incompatible conditional operand types Activity and TaskComplianceActivity
TaskComplianceActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Testing the instance is in most cases bad smelling code. If it is possible to do the special handling right in TaskComplianceActivity this would be the prefered solution - just a thought...

Comment: "Incompatible conditional operand types" sounds like a compile error, so how can you "step through the code" if the code doesn't compile?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if (activity.getClass().getName().equals(TaskComplianceActivity.class.getName()))
```

or this:

```
if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(TaskComplianceActivity.class.getSimpleName()))
```

Comment: i didnt downvote, but obviously because you dont compare strings that way.

Comment: I get the error "TaskComplianceActivity cannot be resolved to a type" when I try your second one with `getSimpleName()`. It definitely exists though! What am I doing wrong?